# HashMap for classes, not objects

Tags: java

I want to assign ui-Classes to a model-class each. By this I want to find the class where to store the date from the user interface. Please don't refer to the design but to my question on a `HashMap`'s usage ;-)

I am aware of the class `HashMap` but only used it to assign objects to other objects.

How can I manage to link always two CLASSES with each other?

```
public static final HashMap<class,class> componentMap=new HashMap<class, class>();
componentMap.put(ToolPanel.class, ToolComponent.class);
```

The code above does not work...

Answer (score 34):

You want a `Map<Class<?>, Class<?>>`.

`Class` here refers to [`java.lang.Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), which is a generified type. Unless you have more specific bounds, the unbounded wildcard `<?>` can be used (see *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 23: Don't use raw types in new code*)

Note that the `interface Map` is used here instead of a specific implementation `HashMap` (see *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*).

Note that `Map<Class<?>, Class<?>>` still maps objects, but the type of those objects are now `Class<?>`. They are still objects nonetheless.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorial/Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html) ([original dead link from Archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20100803045643/http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html))
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)
- [JLS 15.8.2 Class Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2)

  > A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a `class` [...] followed by a `.` and the token `class`. The type of a class literal, `C.class`, where `C` is the name of a `class` [...] is `Class<C>`.

#### Related questions

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

#### Imposing restrictions with bounded wilcards

Here's an example of imposing bounded wildcards to have a `Map` whose keys must be `Class<? extends Number>`, and values can be any `Class<?>`.

```
    Map<Class<? extends Number>, Class<?>> map
        = new HashMap<Class<? extends Number>, Class<?>>();

    map.put(Integer.class, String.class);        // OK!
    map.put(Long.class, StringBuilder.class);    // OK!

    map.put(String.class, Boolean.class);        // NOT OK!
    // Compilation error:
    //     The method put(Class<? extends Number>, Class<?>)
    //     in the type Map<Class<? extends Number>,Class<?>>
    //     is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>, Class<Boolean>)
```

As you can see, the generic compile-time typesafety mechanism will prevent `String.class` from being used as a key, since `String` does not `extends Number`.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics/More Fun with Wildcards](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ/What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103)

Comment: I only have the constraints that the key-class extends ClassR and the value-class extends classB. Can this be specified in the generics?

Comment: @kerrl - `Map<Class<? extends ClassR>, Class<? extends ClassB>>`

Answer (score 3):

It should have been:

```
HashMap<Class,Class>
```

(capital C)

or better:

```
HashMap<Class<?>,Class<?>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
To what extend does Class<?> differ to Class, what's the generic's effect?

Answer (score 2):

The declaration should be:

```
public static final HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>> componentMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
```